# Convert a recurrence relationship into an algebraic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have a piece of code that describes a recursive relationship to produce a logarithmic sweep:

```
StartFreq = 1;
EndFreq = 10;
SweepDuration = 100;

k = exp(ln(EndFreq/StartFreq)/SweepDuration);

freq(0) = StartFreq;
for (i=n;n<100;n++){
    freq(n) = freq(n-1)*k;
}
```

I am trying to convert this recursive relationship into an algebraic expression $f(n)$. (Actually I wanted $f(t)$, in this case here we're sampling at 1Hz so the math kind of works out in this case.) I have other code snippets that are similar but I wanted to try to solve those myself. I just kind of wanted to get a walk through the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding here. Your $k$ as defined is constant. Your recurrence seems to be 
$$f(n) = f(n-1)\cdot k$$
$$f(0) = a$$
where $a$ is your start frequency. So its simple to work out that
$$f(1) = f(0)\cdot k = ak$$
$$f(2) = f(1)\cdot k = ak^2$$
$$\cdots$$
and in general
$$f(n) = ak^n$$
I'm also not too sure what you meant by "I want $f(t)$".

Comment: late friday is not a good time to post questions. I feel really dumb for not figuring that out on my own.